# Webpack 4 Dev Server config with back end using virtual host

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm working on a project split into 2 parts (on the same machine) :

- a front end using Webpack 4,
- a back end coded with PHP.

I'm running Webpack Dev Server with the following config :

```
...
devServer: {
    contentBase: '../backend/public',
    compress: true,
    proxy: {
        "/backend": {
            target: "http://localhost:3000",
            pathRewrite: {"^/backend" : ""}
        }
    },
    hot: true
},
...
```

This works like a charm and every time the front end request something like

```
/backend/users/login
```

it correctly requests my back end to:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/login
```

But I would like to access to my back end with an Apache virtual host that works on my machine. So instead of having

```
http://localhost:3000/users/login
```

I have :

```
http://my-wonderful-virtualhost.com/users/login
```

So I changed the Webpack config :

```
...
devServer: {
    contentBase: '../backend/public',
    compress: true,
    proxy: {
        "/backend": {
            target: "http://my-wonderful-virtualhost.com",
            pathRewrite: {"^/backend" : ""}
        }
    },
    hot: true
},
...
```

But is doesn't work. The request is sent to

```
http://localhost:8080/backend/users/login
```

instead. Accessing http://my-wonderful-virtualhost.com/users/login directly in my brother does work.

How can I use my virtual host?